# Detect if form onSubmit() returns false

Tags: javascript, html

So, I understand that

```html
<div class="form"><form method="Post" action="./index.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
```

redirects me to index.php if my `validateForm()` is true. But how to do something (for example add cookie that says "Form is not valid") if validate is false?

Comment: Either do that in your `validateForm` function before returning `false`, or create a new function which uses `validateForm()` internally, if you don't want to change it

Comment: You have more control if you use ajax. You can check the success and failure cases with it

Answer (score 0):

From the validateForm function, if your condition is false then redirect it to a function for further processing.

Event handlers like onsubmit run before default actions. and cancel the actions onSubmit is false.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the result of `validateForm()` in a variable, and check inline if the value is `false`. If it is, call another function like so:

```js
function validateForm() {
  return false;
}

function ifFalse() {
  console.log("false");
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <form method="Post" action="./index.php" onsubmit="
  x=validateForm();
  if(!x){
    ifFalse();
  }
  return x;
  ">
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Although it is best to handle this inside the `validateForm()` method, since inline JavaScript is generally discouraged.